# Universal iPhone/iPad project with iAd framework

Tags: iphone, ipad, frameworks, universal-binary

how can I set up a Universal project which has support for iAd (just in the iPhone app)?

Using the iPhone SDK 4, let's suppose I do the following steps:

1. Open XCode;
2. Go to File > New Project ;
3. Select Window-based application (or whatever), choose Product: **Universal** (and after choose a name for the project).

It will create a Universal project skeleton with iPhone/iPad groups as usual.
Now, I decide to integrate iAd in my iPhone App, so I do the following:

1. Right-click in the project's group called Frameworks > Add > Existing Frameworks...
2. Choose **iAd.framework** > Add

So far, so good. I can simply Build And Run using the Active Executable as **Project Name - iPhone Simulator 4.0** and the project runs OK. Suppose I change the Active Executable to  **Project Name - iPad Simulator 3.2**. Although the iAd.framework is still being referenced in the Frameworks successfully (without being marked with the Red color), the App crashed in the iPad simulator and I get the following error message:

*dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework/iAd
  Referenced from: /Users/nexia1/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.2/Applications/8479EE14-28AA-4628-A668-CCF3FE770628/Untitled.app/Untitled
  Reason: image not found*

Can I use the iAd in such a Universal project? (even that I only references it in my iPhone app).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to weak link the framework, and in your code ask if the classes exist.

Apple has a similar example for this: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MailComposer/index.html

It is about the in-app mail sheet on 3.0 while still running on 2.x, but you'll get the point.

Comment: Thanks Eiko, that solved my problem!
For simplicity purposes, the steps are as follows: Go into Targets > Select the Target and click Info. In the Linked Libraries selected the iAd.framework and change the Type from Required to Weak.

Thanks!

Comment: also check UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone before sending messages to the the ADBannerView or else you might get some crashes